# `withFilter' method does not yet exist on org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am building spark project with SBT (scala version 2.10.4):

> sbt -Pyarn -Phadoop-2.4 -Dhadoop.version=2.4.0 -Phive
>   -Phive-thriftserver -DskipTests clean package

Then I obtain the following error:

> [error]
>   /home/gracer/Desktop/test/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ml/recommendation/contextaware/CAMFCU.scala:1514:
>   `withFilter' method does not yet exist on
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Int,
>   scala.collection.mutable.Map[Long,Float])], using`filter' method
>   instead [error]     for ((bid, errors) <- errorsTerms) {

The strange thing is that I was previously able to compile and execute the project, but for some reason it now gives an error.

Comment: Are you using `-Xfatal-warnings` ?

Comment: @m-z: No. What does it serve for and how to use it?